# Cordova - Onsen UI won't execute scripts

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using Cordova with pure JavaScript.
I'm trying to get the `ons.ready()` to execute from a JavaScript file called `ui.js`, except it doesn't work.
It looks something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Everything executes up to this line
    ons.ready(function () {
        // Nothing executes here
    });
});
```

The thing is, it doesn't work only when I execute it on my Android device - when tried to execute the script in a localhost in the browser, it perfectly worked.
And since the version that doesn't work is the Android one - I cannot really debug the app to try to understand how to fix it.

If it's relevant, I'm using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) to edit my Cordova app, as well as manage my Node.js packages.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by removing the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` part.
Result:

```
ons.ready(function () {
    // Code goes here
});
```